# Why am I getting this error when using add() and getFirst() for a LinkedList?

Tags: java

This the code I have:

```
public class FlightMap implements FlightMapInterface {

LinkedList<City> cityList = new LinkedList<City>();
LinkedList<City> nextCity = new LinkedList<City>();

/**
 * Creates an empty FlightMap
 */
public FlightMap() {        
}


public void loadFlightMap(String cityFileName, String flightFileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException {

    File cityList = new File(cityFileName);
    File flightsTo = new File (flightFileName);

    Scanner theCityFile = null;
    Scanner theFlightFile = null;
    Scanner theRequestFile = null;

    ArrayList<String> cityStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    int counter = 0;

    try {
        theCityFile = new Scanner (cityList);
        theFlightFile = new Scanner (flightsTo);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No such file exists.");
    }

    while (theFlightFile.hasNextLine()) {
        cityStringList.add((theFlightFile.nextLine()).replaceAll("\t", ""));
    }

    while (theCityFile.hasNextLine()) {
        LinkedList<City> tempList = new LinkedList<City>();
        String tempCity = theCityFile.nextLine();
        nextCity.add(tempList); // ERROR
        nextCity.get(counter).add(new City(tempCity)); // ERROR

        for (int x = 0; x < cityStringList.size(); x++) {
            if (cityStringList.get(x).charAt(0) == tempCity.charAt(0)) {
                insertAdjacent(nextCity.get(counter).getFirst(), // ERROR
                        new City(cityStringList.get(x)).charAt(1) + "");  // ERROR
            }
        }
        cityList.add(new City(tempCity)); // ERROR
        counter++;
    }
}
```

And for my error:

- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
  problems:
- The method add(City) in the type LinkedList is not applicable for the arguments (LinkedList)
- The method add(City) is undefined for the type City
- The method getFirst() is undefined for the type City
- The method charAt(int) is undefined for the type City

Comment: What lines are these errors reported for?

Comment: It doesn't tell me, but I'll mark them in.

Comment: If you want to add each element of a list to another list (containing the same type), use [List.addAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)).

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what the error says.

```
LinkedList<City> tempList = new LinkedList<City>();
String tempCity = theCityFile.nextLine();
nextCity.add(tempList);
```

Should probably be

```
String tempCity = theCityFile.nextLine();
nextCity.add(tempCity);
```

You attempted to add a `LinkedList` to another `LinkedList`. You can only add "nodes" of type `City` to the `LinkedList` that you declared.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `add()` a list to your `LinkedList<City>` - its elements must be of type `City`, not of type `List<City>`. You can use `addAll` instead. You then try to `add` a `City` to your `City`, rather than to your `List` - apparently `City` doesn't have an `Add` method. Likewise with the `getFirst` and the `charAt` - you keep treating your `City` objects as if they are `List`s or `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a number of things which don't make sense, so you get these errors.

> The method add(City) in the type LinkedList is not applicable for the arguments (LinkedList)

You are attempting to add a List of City to a List of City.

> The method add(City) is undefined for the type City

You are attempting to add a City to a City (rather than a List of City and you haven't defined such a method.

> The method getFirst() is undefined for the type City
>   The method charAt(int) is undefined for the type City

You haven't defined those methods, so you can't call them.

Answer (score 0):

In this code here:

```
    LinkedList<City> tempList = new LinkedList<City>();
    String tempCity = theCityFile.nextLine();
    nextCity.add(tempList);
```

You are attempting to add a `LinkedList<City>` to your `nextCity` list which is what the error states.

Answer (score 0):

First of all nextCity is of type LinkedList<City> so you cant add a LinkedList to it:

```
nextCity.add(tempList);
```

Use instead:

```
nextCity.addAll(tempList);
```

The same problem is with:

```
nextCity.get(counter).add(new City(tempCity));
```

You are getting the city and adding again a city to it.

Comment: Actually, `nextCity` is a `LinkedList<City>` - read the OP's source.

Comment: @Adrian - I meant that the LinkedList(because it's a generic) is of type City but i edited it so it's clearer